# The CNN model does not learn when adding one/two more convolutional layers

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to implement the model in the picture in tensorflow. Just instead of 6 output neurons I have 1000. I am doing this to have pretrained weights.[image]

I implemented the full model but with only one (14,14,128) layer; just for testing and so on. Now that the porgram is matured I implemented the two more layers (or one). This makes the model not learning anything; loss is constant (around a small noise) and the accuracy tested on the training images is constant at random guess. Befor adding the layers I could get very fast (5-10 min) to accuracy of 70-80 percent in 1000 image-subset from the train dataset. As said this is not the case with the additional layers.

Here is the code for the additional layer where `s1` and `s2` is the stride of the conv:

```py
w2 = weight_variable([3,3,64,128])
b2 = bias_variable([128])
h2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d_s2(h1_pool,w2)+b2)
h2_pool = max_pool_2x2(h2)

#Starts additional layer
w3 = weight_variable([3,3,128,128])
b3 = bias_variable([128])
h3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d_s1(h2_pool,w3)+b3)
#Ends additional layer

w5 = weight_variable([3,3,128,256])
b5 = bias_variable([256])
h5 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d_s1(h3,w5)+b5)
h5_pool = max_pool_2x2(h5)
```

This extra layer makes the model worthless. I have tried different hyperparameters (learning rate, batch size, epochs) without success. Where lies the problem?

Another question could be: does anyone know a small (and/or better) network of this size so I can imprement and test. My goal is to detect grasp positions in different objects (images of objects)?

If it helps, I use one GTX 980 with a very very good xeon.

The repository can be found in https://github.com/tnikolla/grasp-detection.

**UPDATE**

*The problem was divergence in loss. Solved by lowering the learning rate*

In orange is the accuracy and loss (tensorboard and terminal) when the program showed no learning at all. I was fooled by the loss showed in termminal. As pointed by @hars to check the logs of accuracy and loss I discovered that the loss in tensorboard diverges in the first steps. By changing the learning rate from 0,01 to 0,001 the divergence dissapeared and as you can see in cyan the model was learning (overfited a small subset of imagente in 1 minute).[image][image][image]

Comment: would you post your complete model code and training/optimizer code and parameters ?

Comment: Here is the [github](https://github.com/tnikolla/grasp-detection) link.

Comment: Adding layers does not always improve performance as then the optimization problem is harder, have you tried using Batch Normalization?

Comment: I will add Batch Normalization. I want also dropout. But first some data augmentation. I am enriching the program one method at a time and accompanying it with paper reading, experimentation, tensorflow, .... I am using this project to gather some knowledge and experience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a ReLU layer at the end of the model which might be clipping all gradients, followed by a softmax with logits in the training part. Therefore, the model might get stuck at poor local-minima.

Try removing tf.nn.relu in the last line of your inference and see if it trains well.

Here is your part of the code:

last few lines of model :

```py
# fc1 layer
W_fc3 = weight_variable([512, 1000])
b_fc3 = bias_variable([1000])
output = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc2, W_fc3) + b_fc3)
#print("output: {}".format(output.get_shape()))

return output
```

training part of the code:

```py
logits = inference_redmon.inference(images)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits=logits, labels=labels_one))        
tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
correct_pred = tf.equal( tf.argmax(logits,1), tf.argmax(labels_one,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean( tf.cast( correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

Comment: Thanks @hars. It must have slipped. But I still don't know why it was working with the simpler network? Can you elaborate a little (maybe editing your accepted answer) or give me a link?

Comment: I guess, your dataset is small enough and local minima got decent performance. May be you will get better performance if you don't have it. You can test it by removing relu in 1-layer network.

Comment: Although you cought a bug, this didn't solved the problem. I made an error when running the program. I made the change in the `inference_redmon.inference` but executed again the `inference.inference`. Sorry for the trouble. If you can see some other thing missing, I would be greatful. Cheers.

Comment: would you please update your github code. I am confused with what changes you made and what script you are running ? Also, please add new loss/accuracy logs as UPDATE to your post.

Comment: I took out relu from the output layer in `inference_redmon.py` but executed `inference.py`. Anyway, by checking the loss in tensorboard and not in terminal I could see the divergence. By lowering ten times the learning rate the divergence dissapeared and of course the model could be trained. Thanks for pointing in the right direction (two times).